# When passing null to Interop method it throws "Generic types cannot be marshaled." exception

Tags: c#, generics, interop

I'm working with a C++ dll that is imported like this:

```
    [DllImport("Bank.dll"]
    static extern int GetDevice(byte versionCode, byte deviceAddress);
```

I can successfully access this method with not null arguments like this:

```
    GetDevice(0, 3);
```

But calling this method with null arguments like this:

```
    [DllImport("Bank.dll"]
    static extern int GetDevice(byte versionCode, Nullable<byte> deviceAddress);
    GetDevice(0, null);
```

Gives the following runtime error:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred.
Additional information: Cannot marshal 'parameter #2': Generic types cannot be marshaled.*

How do I successfully pass null arguments to this method?

Comment: You must post the C++ declaration of the function.  But strong hint that you are trying to do something nonsensical if the first C# declaration is anywhere near correct, null is only appropriate for pointer types, not byte.  And Nullable<> can never work, there is no corresponding C++ type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing that you have mistaken `Nullable<byte>` as being equivalent to C++'s `unsigned char *` or similar. It's not. It is literally a *single* `byte`, but where the value can also be `null`.

As the error message says, you also are not permitted to pass generic types, and of course `Nullable<T>` is a generic type. So even if it semantically meant what you wanted, it wouldn't be allowed.

But per your question, "How do I successfully pass null arguments to this method?", that suggests that what you are really dealing with is a pointer type as the parameter type. Without a [complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to know for sure what your declaration and usage should be. But it's likely you can just declare the parameters as a `byte[]`, and p/invoke will marshal it correctly, including mapping a managed null reference to a null pointer.

I.e. just declare your method like this:

```
[DllImport("Bank.dll"]
static extern int GetDevice(byte versionCode, byte[] deviceAddress);
```

The default marshaling should work for you. If not, then you'll need to edit your question to include the exact C++ declaration you're trying to call.